# Problems searching with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySQL, i'm building a search form where the user will be able to search products searching the terms from two columns on the MySQL table. I have the column "Modelo" and the column "Concepto". When i try to search values that you can find in "Concepto" it works well, but it doesn't work well when the value is in "Modelo".

This is the syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM hoja1
WHERE Concepto LIKE '%$buscar%' or
  Modelo LIKE '%$buscar%'
LIMIT $inicio, $TAMANO_PAGINA
```

For example, I have this values on the column Modelo

```
8345GS
FLEX AUT 1
```

If i search 8354GS it doesn't work, nothing appears on the screen. But if i find only `GS` the form can find the value. The same with "FLEX AUT 1", when i search for `FLEX AUT 1` it appears nothing, but with `FLEX` there are no problem. In fact, my code can't search entire values on `Modelo` column. But there are no problem when i search for values on the table `Concepto`

Sorry for my english. I hope u can help me.

Comment: You say you search for `8354GS` (five-four), but in your example it's `8345GS` (four-five). Typo?

Comment: Can you please show the Create table query associated with your table? i.e. show us your table design.

Comment: There was a mistake writing the value here.

Comment: ¿The create table query? i don't understand

Comment: Type "Show Create Table hoja1" into mysql and post the result.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `hoja1` (
 `Modelo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Concepto` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Precio` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Imagen` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Categoría` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: I see more than one problem that needs fixing here. There is no primary key (`id` column), the price column should be a `decimal`, category should be an `int` pointing to the `categories` table (you do have a `categories` table, with an `id` column as `int`, right?) and several of them should probably be `not null` as well. What I don't see is anything that could be the cause of this problem, unless the values passed into `limit` are making it skip the results you want.

Comment: Please tell me you're escaping those parameters properly. [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) explains how.

Comment: Yes, i worked on it, i defina a Primary Key and those things but I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The first record is #0, so make sure your `$inicio` starts at 0, not 1.