# I can't find the exact value on MySQL when i have only one value on the table

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problems searching with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726048/problems-searching-with-mysql)

I have a problem, i made a search form with this syntaxis.

The problem is that if i find the exact value it finds me nothing.

for example, if i have only one value with "8345GS" it shows me nothing, but if i have 3 or 4 rows with the same value it works. I don't know what's the problem, this is the declaration

```
SELECT * FROM hoja1 WHERE Modelo LIKE '%$buscar%' or Concepto LIKE '%$buscar%' LIMIT $inicio, $TAMANO_PAGINA
```

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

$inicio must start with zero, surely you are using one on it. That is the reason because only having more than 1 row you could see results.